# org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde$OrcSerdeRow

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am getting the following exception while loading an ORC table which is clustered by page_id column. Without the the clustering the table just loads fine.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde$OrcSerdeRow    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcOutputFormat.java:80)  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:621)     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExtractOperator.processOp(ExtractOperator.java:45)    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:262)   ... 7 more

Comment: please provide query ?